# How are 2D views from a 3D CAD Model stored in STEP-File with Boundary Representation generate for engineers to define details? And why?

Tags: structural-engineering, cad, technical-drawing, 3d-printing, autocad

I am new in this topic and need some help. There are 3D CAD models (stored as STEP Files with the boundary representation) and some engineers need 2D views of these models for further processing. With these 2D views, they define some production specific details such as tolerance of a drill hole etc. But they do it just in those 2 views from the CAD Model. So these 2D models are used as a supplement to technical drawings.

I am new to this. What is the expert / domain name for this 2D views? And how is this task/process step called where one uses 2D views of 3D model to specify details for the production?

In the derived 2D model, is it always a single surface of the 3D Model?

What is a typical software that generates these 2D tools and what is the file format? I dont understand why they do not use the 3D CAD model?

Thanks for any clarification

Edit:

**3D Model:**
[image]

**Corresponding 2D Model - How is this file saved? Which format?:**
[image]

Comment: step tends to be used a lot for interchange of 3D between CAD software.  Equivalent interchange for 2D is likely dxf (which can also store 3D)

Comment: that's a `side view`